# NPE on java stream reduce operation

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Recently, while working with Java 8 streams, I came across a `NullPointerException` on a reduce operation while working with the following test cases:

```
private static final BinaryOperator<Integer> sum = (a, b) -> {
    if (a == null) return b;
    if (b == null) return a;
    return Integer.sum(a, b);
};

List<Integer> s = new ArrayList<>();
s.add(null);
s.add(null);
s.add(null);

Integer i = s.stream().reduce(sum).orElse(null);
// throws NPE

Integer i = s.stream().reduce(sum).orElse(2);
// throws NPE

Integer i = s.stream().reduce(null,(a, b)->null);
// returns a value i.e null
```

Or alternatively:

```
Integer i = s.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).reduce(Integer::sum).orElse(null);
// returns a value i.e null
```

Upon checking the reduce operation, I came across this class which performs the reduce operation:

```
class ReducingSink implements AccumulatingSink<T, Optional<T>, ReducingSink> {
    private boolean empty;
    private T state;

    public void begin(long size) {
        empty = true;
        state = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void accept(T t) {
        if (empty) {
            empty = false;
            state = t;
        } else {
            state = operator.apply(state, t);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<T> get() {
        return empty ? Optional.empty() : Optional.of(state);
    }

    @Override
    public void combine(ReducingSink other) {
        if (!other.empty)
            accept(other.state);
    }
}
```

In the above code, you see that the `get()` method returns an optional value if the boolean `empty` is false, and in my case the value is false but `state` is null, so `Optional.of(null)` throws a `NullPointerException`. In my case I have a binary operator which allows `null`.

So I think the code

```
return empty ? Optional.empty() : Optional.of(state);
```

should be changed to

```
return empty || state == null ? Optional.empty() : Optional.of(state);
```

As my binary operator (which has the task of reducing) and is okay with `null`.

Comment: How about `Optional.ofNullable`? Anyway your example doesn't look right since you are using `List<Integer>` with `BinaryOperator<Double>`.

Comment: @Pshemo `ReducingSink` is an internal jdk class

Comment: Anyways - @Pshemo is right -  the example doesn't compile very well :-)

Comment: BinaryOperator<Double> was by mistake copied, it actually meant BinaryOperator<Integer> and through this example i just want to highlight the posibility of an BinaryOperator which can handle null values but the expression gives NPE.

Comment: You wasted so much time studying the source code, instead of looking into the documentation for one second, to learn that the behavior is intentional…

Comment: I got that the behavior is intentional, just wanted to understand their intention

Answer (score 10):

I can't really tell why you *have to work* with nulls, this seems like a bad a idea to begin with. And, as you have seen you can't `reduce` using a null as input. You could build your own custom `Collector` (you can't build your own `Reducer`).

What you have in place:

```
 Double result = s.stream()
         .filter(Objects::nonNull)
         .reduce(Double::sum)
         .orElse(null);
```

is **perfectly fine** btw. The only way to get a null result is when *all* elements from your input are null, thus filtering them initially is the way to go. For the fun of it I decided to write a custom collector (can't really tell why, thought it would be fun I guess)

```
 Double result = s.stream()
          .parallel()
          .collect(
                () -> new Double[] { null }, 
                (left, right) -> {
                    if (right != null) {
                       if (left[0] != null) {
                           left[0] = right + left[0];
                       } else {
                            left[0] = right;
                       }
                    }
                }, 
                (left, right) -> {
                   if (right[0] != null) {
                        if (left[0] != null) {
                            left[0] = right[0] + left[0];
                        } else {
                             left[0] = right[0];
                        }
                }})[0];
```

You could put this into a class itself if needed:

```
 class NullableCollector implements Collector<Double, Double[], Double> {

    @Override
    public BiConsumer<Double[], Double> accumulator() {
        return (left, right) -> {
            if (right != null) {
                if (left[0] != null) {
                    left[0] = right + left[0];
                } else {
                    left[0] = right;
                }
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
        return EnumSet.noneOf(Characteristics.class);
    }

    @Override
    public BinaryOperator<Double[]> combiner() {
        return (left, right) -> {
            if (right[0] != null) {
                if (left[0] != null) {
                    left[0] = right[0] + left[0];
                } else {
                    left[0] = right[0];
                }
            }
            return left;
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Function<Double[], Double> finisher() {
        return (array) -> array[0];
    }

    @Override
    public Supplier<Double[]> supplier() {
        return () -> new Double[] { null };
    }

}
```

Answer (score 8):

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) of the reduce operation that you use states:

> Throws:
>       NullPointerException - if the result of the reduction is null

So the NPE that you see is documented and intended outcome even if your binary operator is fine with null.

The documentation is even more verbose giving extra insight with some equivalent code:

```
     boolean foundAny = false;
     T result = null;
     for (T element : this stream) {
         if (!foundAny) {
             foundAny = true;
             result = element;
         }
         else
             result = accumulator.apply(result, element);
     }
     return foundAny ? Optional.of(result) : Optional.empty();
```

NPE is thrown on the last line in this case.

If your suggested change is applied in the library we won't be able to distinguish the result of reducing an empty stream from a stream in which the result of the reduction is null.

Comment: I agree with you on point that if the suggested change is applied then we wont be able to differentiate between the  result of reducing an empty stream from a stream in which the result of the reduction is null but can you suggest a use case for it.

Comment: Well... a stream with your incredible achievements in Game X and an application that prints "Your total avhievement is... " or "You still haven't played this game, try it out!", things like that :-)

Answer (score 2):

About the reason *why* they decided not to deal with `null` values I suspect it has something to do with the fact that `Optional.of` takes a *mandatory* value and you have to use the special factory `ofNullable` to deal with actually optional variables...
For the *how* to achieve the reduction I have a solution: it's a bit clunky, but you can use only built-in stream transformations.
First of all, change your accumulator to work with `Optional` instead of `null`:

```java
private static final BinaryOperator<Optional<Integer>> sum = (a, b) -> a.isPresent()?
        (b.isPresent()? a.map(n -> b.get() + n) : a) : b;
```

Then wrap your elemnts in an `Optional` before reducing and unwrap the result after finishing:

```java
Integer i = s.stream()
   .map(Optional::ofNullable)    // wrap nullables into Optional
   .reduce(sum)                  // get an Optional<Optional<Integer>>
   .flatMap(Function.identity()) // unwrap to an Optional<Integer>
   .orElse(null);                // if stream is empty or reduction is emptyOptional
```